# Unable to move Tapestry jars out of the war with page code inside the war still

Tags: tapestry

I'm trying to experiment, as we have multiple web wars and at-least 2 of them using Tapestry 5.4.1 right now.

The idea is move the Tapestry related jars at one place which is out side of the war(s) on the system class path.

But when I try to open a Tapestry page inside a browser it complains about page class/ code not found while preparing to build it for display.

I guess the Tapestry classes which is outside of the war does not see the page class which is inside the WAR.

So is it really possible what i'm trying? To me, it does not look like as Tapestry jars should be at the same level of class path where Tapestry page code is.

Exception trace

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception assembling root component of page ExceptionReport: Exception assembling embedded component 'layout' (of type myproject.web.components.Layout, within ExceptionReport): Could not convert 'style' into a component parameter binding: Exception generating conduit for expression 'style': java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: myproject.web.pages.reassign.ReAssign
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.pageload.ComponentAssemblerImpl.performAssembleRootComponent(ComponentAssemblerImpl.java:129)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.pageload.ComponentAssemblerImpl.access$000(ComponentAssemblerImpl.java:37)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.pageload.ComponentAssemblerImpl$1.invoke(ComponentAssemblerImpl.java:81)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.pageload.ComponentAssemblerImpl$1.invoke(ComponentAssemblerImpl.java:78)
    org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:82)
    org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.PerThreadOperationTracker.invoke(PerThreadOperationTracker.java:72)
    org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.invoke(RegistryImpl.java:1260)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.pageload.ComponentAssemblerImpl.assembleRootComponent(ComponentAssemblerImpl.java:76)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.pageload.PageLoaderImpl$3.invoke(PageLoaderImpl.java:197)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.pageload.PageLoaderImpl$3.invoke(PageLoaderImpl.java:190)
    org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:82)
    org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.PerThreadOperationTracker.invoke(PerThreadOperationTracker.java:72)
    org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.invoke(RegistryImpl.java:1260)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.pageload.PageLoaderImpl.loadPage(PageLoaderImpl.java:189)
    $PageLoader_12d4e53af23f.loadPage(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.PageSourceImpl.getPage(PageSourceImpl.java:104)
    $PageSource_12d4e53af23e.getPage(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.RequestPageCacheImpl.get(RequestPageCacheImpl.java:86)
    $RequestPageCache_12d4e53af23d.get(Unknown Source)
    $RequestPageCache_12d4e53af20f.get(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.DefaultRequestExceptionHandler.renderException(DefaultRequestExceptionHandler.java:254)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.DefaultRequestExceptionHandler.handleRequestException(DefaultRequestExceptionHandler.java:145)
    $RequestExceptionHandler_12d4e53af1f7.handleRequestException(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.RequestErrorFilter.service(RequestErrorFilter.java:42)
    $RequestHandler_12d4e53af1f9.service(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tapestry5.modules.TapestryModule$3.service(TapestryModule.java:846)
    $RequestHandler_12d4e53af1f9.service(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tapestry5.modules.TapestryModule$2.service(TapestryModule.java:836)
    $RequestHandler_12d4e53af1f9.service(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.StaticFilesFilter.service(StaticFilesFilter.java:89)
    $RequestHandler_12d4e53af1f9.service(Unknown Source)
    $RequestHandler_12d4e53af1ef.service(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tapestry5.modules.TapestryModule$HttpServletRequestHandlerTerminator.service(TapestryModule.java:256)
    org.got5.tapestry5.jquery.services.AjaxUploadServletRequestFilter.service(AjaxUploadServletRequestFilter.java:27)
    $HttpServletRequestHandler_12d4e53af1f1.service(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tapestry5.upload.internal.services.MultipartServletRequestFilter.service(MultipartServletRequestFilter.java:45)
    $HttpServletRequestHandler_12d4e53af1f1.service(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.gzip.GZipFilter.service(GZipFilter.java:59)
    $HttpServletRequestHandler_12d4e53af1f1.service(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.IgnoredPathsFilter.service(IgnoredPathsFilter.java:62)
    $HttpServletRequestFilter_12d4e53af1eb.service(Unknown Source)
    $HttpServletRequestHandler_12d4e53af1f1.service(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tapestry5.modules.TapestryModule$1.service(TapestryModule.java:796)
    $HttpServletRequestHandler_12d4e53af1f1.service(Unknown Source)
    $HttpServletRequestHandler_12d4e53af1ea.service(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tapestry5.TapestryFilter.doFilter(TapestryFilter.java:166)
root cause

org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationException: Exception assembling embedded component 'layout' (of type myproject.web.components.Layout, within ExceptionReport): Could not convert 'style' into a component parameter binding: Exception generating conduit for expression 'style': java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: myproject.web.pages.reassign.ReAssign [at classpath:myproject/web/pages/ExceptionReport.tml, line 3]
    org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.logAndRethrow(OperationTrackerImpl.java:186)
    org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.run(OperationTrackerImpl.java:62)
    org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.PerThreadOperationTracker.run(PerThreadOperationTracker.java:60)
    org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.run(RegistryImpl.java:1254)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.pageload.ComponentAssemblerImpl.assembleEmbeddedComponent(ComponentAssemblerImpl.java:158)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.pageload.PageLoaderImpl$12.execute(PageLoaderImpl.java:963)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.pageload.ComponentAssemblerImpl.runActions(ComponentAssemblerImpl.java:229)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.pageload.ComponentAssemblerImpl.performAssembleRootComponent(ComponentAssemblerImpl.java:105)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.pageload.ComponentAssemblerImpl.access$000(ComponentAssemblerImpl.java:37)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.pageload.ComponentAssemblerImpl$1.invoke(ComponentAssemblerImpl.java:81)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.pageload.ComponentAssemblerImpl$1.invoke(ComponentAssemblerImpl.java:78)
    org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:82)
    org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.PerThreadOperationTracker.invoke(PerThreadOperationTracker.java:72)
    org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.invoke(RegistryImpl.java:1260)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.pageload.ComponentAssemblerImpl.assembleRootComponent(ComponentAssemblerImpl.java:76)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.pageload.PageLoaderImpl$3.invoke(PageLoaderImpl.java:197)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.pageload.PageLoaderImpl$3.invoke(PageLoaderImpl.java:190)
    org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:82)
    org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.PerThreadOperationTracker.invoke(PerThreadOperationTracker.java:72)
    org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.invoke(RegistryImpl.java:1260)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.pageload.PageLoaderImpl.loadPage(PageLoaderImpl.java:189)
    $PageLoader_12d4e53af23f.loadPage(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.PageSourceImpl.getPage(PageSourceImpl.java:104)
    $PageSource_12d4e53af23e.getPage(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.RequestPageCacheImpl.get(RequestPageCacheImpl.java:86)
    $RequestPageCache_12d4e53af23d.get(Unknown Source)
    $RequestPageCache_12d4e53af20f.get(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.DefaultRequestExceptionHandler.renderException(DefaultRequestExceptionHandler.java:254)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.DefaultRequestExceptionHandler.handleRequestException(DefaultRequestExceptionHandler.java:145)
    $RequestExceptionHandler_12d4e53af1f7.handleRequestException(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.RequestErrorFilter.service(RequestErrorFilter.java:42)
    $RequestHandler_12d4e53af1f9.service(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tapestry5.modules.TapestryModule$3.service(TapestryModule.java:846)
    $RequestHandler_12d4e53af1f9.service(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tapestry5.modules.TapestryModule$2.service(TapestryModule.java:836)
    $RequestHandler_12d4e53af1f9.service(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.StaticFilesFilter.service(StaticFilesFilter.java:89)
    $RequestHandler_12d4e53af1f9.service(Unknown Source)
    $RequestHandler_12d4e53af1ef.service(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tapestry5.modules.TapestryModule$HttpServletRequestHandlerTerminator.service(TapestryModule.java:256)
    org.got5.tapestry5.jquery.services.AjaxUploadServletRequestFilter.service(AjaxUploadServletRequestFilter.java:27)
    $HttpServletRequestHandler_12d4e53af1f1.service(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tapestry5.upload.internal.services.MultipartServletRequestFilter.service(MultipartServletRequestFilter.java:45)
    $HttpServletRequestHandler_12d4e53af1f1.service(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.gzip.GZipFilter.service(GZipFilter.java:59)
    $HttpServletRequestHandler_12d4e53af1f1.service(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.IgnoredPathsFilter.service(IgnoredPathsFilter.java:62)
    $HttpServletRequestFilter_12d4e53af1eb.service(Unknown Source)
    $HttpServletRequestHandler_12d4e53af1f1.service(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tapestry5.modules.TapestryModule$1.service(TapestryModule.java:796)
    $HttpServletRequestHandler_12d4e53af1f1.service(Unknown Source)
    $HttpServletRequestHandler_12d4e53af1ea.service(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tapestry5.TapestryFilter.doFilter(TapestryFilter.java:166)
```

Comment: I don't think this comment related to Tapestry, it's rather a Tomcat classpath issue. Where exactly you put Tapestry jars? Make sure you're familiar with this: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/class-loader-howto.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried to move the jars to an external folder and the jars from that location are visible to Common classloader of tomcat using common.loader property referring to all the jars of that external location.

Comment: The issue in my understanding is page class visibility for Tapestry internal classes which are now in parent classloader (common in this case). So, when the first layout page has been requested then Tapestry tries to build &assemble it and control is in Common classloader and when the Tapestry internal classes try to load another page which was injected in the original layout page then it tries to look for that page class (review page in this case) and as page code is still in child classloader which is webappX it could not find that class and fails.

Answer (score 0):

Few days ago, working on a new project under JBoss 7.0.0.GA, I was badly hitted by this problem; I investigated the issue and I found the source of all evil: the class "org.apache.tapestry5.internal.plastic.asm.ClassWriter" of plastic.

The classloader used to find (and load) the classes by plastic is really not compatible with an appserver. An appserver is required to enforce classloaded isolation and plastic ignores this.
Anyway plastic can be patched to solve the issue; here I attach a patch, please I ask to some developer to kindly forward and apply this patch to the 5.4.x branch and to the 5.5.

I also want to give thanks to these guys to helped me to focus the problem:

[Unable to move Tapestry jars out of the war with page code inside the war still](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42423907/unable-to-move-tapestry-jars-out-of-the-war-with-page-code-inside-the-war-still)
https://blog.progs.be/50/tapestry-classloading-problems-on-jboss

Regards

**Here is the original code:**

```
1752 protected String getCommonSuperClass(final String type1, final String type2) {
1753   Class<?> c, d;
1754   ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
1755   try {
1756     c = Class.forName(type1.replace('/', '.'), false, classLoader);
1757     d = Class.forName(type2.replace('/', '.'), false, classLoader);
1758   } catch (Exception e) {
1759     throw new RuntimeException(e.toString());
1760   }
1761   if (c.isAssignableFrom(d)) {
1762     return type1;
1763   }
1764   if (d.isAssignableFrom(c)) {
1765     return type2;
1766   }
1767   if (c.isInterface() || d.isInterface()) {
1768     return "java/lang/Object";
1769   } else {
1770   do {
1771     c = c.getSuperclass();
1772   } while (!c.isAssignableFrom(d));
1773   return c.getName().replace('.', '/');
1774   }
1775 }
```

**Here is the patched code:**

```
1752 protected String getCommonSuperClass(final String type1, final String type2) {
1753   Class<?> c, d;
1754   ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
1755   try {
1756     c = Class.forName(type1.replace('/', '.'), false, classLoader);
1757     d = Class.forName(type2.replace('/', '.'), false, classLoader);
1758   } catch (Exception e) {
// --- ARZILLO PATCH BEGIN -----------------------------------------------------------

         System.err.println("WARNING: type1:" + type1 + ", type2: " + type2 + ", exception: " + e + ", classLoader: " + classLoader +", attempting to use the classloader of the current thread");

         classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
         if ( classLoader != null ) {
           try {
             c = Class.forName(type1.replace('/', '.'), false, classLoader);
             d = Class.forName(type2.replace('/', '.'), false, classLoader);
           }
           catch (Exception e_inner) {
             System.err.println("ERROR 1: type1:" + type1 + ", type2: " + type2 + ", e_inner: " + e_inner + ", classLoader: " + classLoader +", failed even using the classloader of the current thread");
             throw new RuntimeException(e_inner.toString());
           }
         }
         else {
           System.err.println("ERROR 2: type1:" + type1 + ", type2: " + type2 + ", exception: " + e + ", classLoader: " + classLoader +", unable to get the classloader of the current thread");
           throw new RuntimeException(e.toString());
         }
// --- ARZILLO PATCH END ------------------------------------------------    -----------
1760   }
1761   if (c.isAssignableFrom(d)) {
1762     return type1;
1763   }
1764   if (d.isAssignableFrom(c)) {
1765     return type2;
1766   }
1767   if (c.isInterface() || d.isInterface()) {
1768     return "java/lang/Object";
1779   } else {
1770     do {
1771       c = c.getSuperclass();
1772     } while (!c.isAssignableFrom(d));
1773   return c.getName().replace('.', '/');
1774   }
1775 }
```